Atiyah and Macdonald Proposition 7.9.
Proposition 7.9 in Atiyah and Macdonald is:

Proposition 7.9. Let $k$ be a field, $E$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra. If $E$ is a field then it is a finite algebraic extension of $k$.

And the beginning of their proof is:

Proof. Let $E=k\left[x_1, \ldots, x_n\right]$. If $E$ is not algebraic over $k$ then we can renumber the $x_i$ so that $x_1, \ldots, x_r$ are algebraically independent over $k$, where $r \geqslant 1$, and each of $x_{r+1}, \ldots, x_n$ is algebraic over the field $F=k\left(x_1, \ldots, x_r\right)$. Hence $E$ is a finite algebraic extension of $F$ and therefore finitely generated as an $F$-module. Applying (7.8) to $k \subseteq F \subseteq E$, it follows that $F$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, say $F=k\left[y_1, \ldots, y_s\right]$. Each $y_j$ is of the form $f_j / g_j$, where $f_j$ and $g_j$ are polynomials in $x_1, \ldots, x_r$.

I understand everything until the last sentence, but then I'm lost. How do we know each $y_j$ is of this form?

Remember that $F=k\left(x_1, \ldots, x_r\right)$, so every element of $F$ looks like $f/g$.

can you tell us what 7.8 is?

Presumably the Artin-Tate lemma.
